# How i can convert list value in String in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have some values store in my database in this format  `["Same Drive","Test Drive","Safe Drive"]`, and same values are displaying on my HTML page, I want to display these values in this format `Same, Test, Safe Drive`, Please let me know how I can display these values in this formant.

here is my HTML file code..

```
<p>{{datas.types}}</p>
```

and this is displaying data in this format `["Same Drive","Test Drive","Safe Drive"]`

Comment: what is the relation between `["Same Drive","Test Drive","Safe Drive"]` and `Same, Test, Safe Drive` ? What is the logic behind the conversion?

Comment: these  values `["Same Drive","Test Drive","Safe Drive"]` are storing in `type` field in my database table, and i want to display in this format `Same, Test, Safe Drive`, because I do not want to repeat `Drive` work every time...

Comment: What database are you using? Is the list stored as a string and you need to parse out the words you want?

Comment: Could it be possible the output of above code in this format `Same, Test, Safe Drive` or in this format `Same Drive, Test Drive, Safe Drive`, I want to remove `" "` and `comma`

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, can you post the query that you're using?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Django template filters inside your template.

```
{{ datas.types|join:", " }}.
```

You can find more about Django template filter here: [Django template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#filters).

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a ***normal join***, see the *"required output"*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes, you are right. I missed that 'drive' was omitted in the first 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template tag which converts this string which is in the format `["Same Drive","Test Drive","Safe Drive"]` into a python list using `json` and returning a string in the desired format.

```py
# your_app/templatetags/custom_tags.py

from django import template

import json

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='convert_list_to_string')
def convert_list_to_string(value):
   data = json.loads(value) # convert string to list
   return ', '.join([e for e in data]) # create a string and return
```

in your template you can use this as

```
{% load custom_tags %}

<p>{{ datas.types|convert_list_to_string }}</p>
```

Create custom template tags [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)